# My goal is to use a text box and save button to import the text box information into google sheets

Tags: python

This is my first attempt at any of this, I haven't been able to google, chat GPT or bard, the correct video or tutorial on how to accomplish my goal.

I know I need to save the information in the text box from line 26-27
((textbox = tk.Text(root, height=7, width= 50, font=('Arial', 16))
textbox.pack()))

I believe after that I can use
wks.update('A2, (not sure what would go here either))

however in the google sheet I do not know how to make the next entry go down to Line A3 then A4 ect

I know the next box says "what did you try and what you were expecting", I couldn't find any starting points to even start with, so that would be appreciated and the spaghettis is below.

thank you in advance

I solved it this is the code I am using, you can change the

```
sh = sa.open("ClientList")
wks = sh.worksheet("Cold Information")
```

to match your spread sheet in google sheets and it will import the text into A2, leaving A1 blank for a header. Next step is to loop it so it will post the next save to A3 instead of A2.

Look out for new post I'm going a different route then this for my database. It's going to be handled in python and exported based off the the user needs from check boxes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import gspread

root = tk.Tk()

#Authentication
sa = gspread.service_account()
#Defining workspace
sh = sa.open("ClientList")
wks = sh.worksheet("Cold Information")

#GUI Frame
root.geometry("800x500")
root.title ("Client Infromation Entry System (CIES)")
root.resizable(False, False)

#Text Box Label
label = tk.Label(root, text="Client Infromation", font=('Arial', 20))
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
      
#Text box
textbox = tk.Text(root, height=7, width= 50, font=('Arial', 16))
textbox.pack()

#Text grabber
def save():
    wks.update_acell('A2', (textbox.get('1.0', END)))
    
#Text Clearer
def clear():
    textbox.delete('1.0', END)

#Button Frame Work
buttonframe = tk.Frame(root)
buttonframe.pack()
buttonframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
buttonframe.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
buttonframe.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

Savebtn = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Save Client Infromation", font=('Arial', 16), command=save)
Savebtn.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

Clearbtn = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Clear Client Infromation", font=('Arial', 16), command=clear)
Clearbtn.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

Quitbtn = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Quit", width=11, font=('Arial', 16), command=quit)
Quitbtn.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.W+tk.E,)

#Loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please repost your code. [formatting code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: I updated to the formatting code, thank you!

Comment: wks.append_row will append instead of update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this is the code I am using, you can change the

```
sh = sa.open("ClientList")
wks = sh.worksheet("Cold Information")
```

to match your spread sheet in google sheets and it will import the text into A2, leaving A1 blank for a header. Next step is to loop it so it will post the next save to A3 instead of A2.

Look out for new post I'm going a different route then this for my database. It's going to be handled in python and exported based off the the user needs from check boxes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import gspread

root = tk.Tk()

#Authentication
sa = gspread.service_account()
#Defining workspace
sh = sa.open("ClientList")
wks = sh.worksheet("Cold Information")

#GUI Frame
root.geometry("800x500")
root.title ("Client Infromation Entry System (CIES)")
root.resizable(False, False)

#Text Box Label
label = tk.Label(root, text="Client Infromation", font=('Arial', 20))
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
      
#Text box
textbox = tk.Text(root, height=7, width= 50, font=('Arial', 16))
textbox.pack()

#Text grabber
def save():
    wks.update_acell('A2', (textbox.get('1.0', END)))
    
#Text Clearer
def clear():
    textbox.delete('1.0', END)

#Button Frame Work
buttonframe = tk.Frame(root)
buttonframe.pack()
buttonframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
buttonframe.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
buttonframe.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

Savebtn = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Save Client Infromation", font=('Arial', 16), command=save)
Savebtn.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

Clearbtn = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Clear Client Infromation", font=('Arial', 16), command=clear)
Clearbtn.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

Quitbtn = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Quit", width=11, font=('Arial', 16), command=quit)
Quitbtn.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.W+tk.E,)

#Loop
root.mainloop()
```